# How to Enter Address in LyX in this form

Tags: formatting, lyx, addresses

I am currently in article AMS document class. In LyX I'd like to enter my name and address in the following form:

[image]

Note that there's not a large gap between the author's name and the address. I would prefer not to include the address in the author section (since I am creating a 2-sided document whose headers alternate between a short title and the author).

In LyX I have two options that I am aware of:

1. Use `Address` mode in Front Matter. The problem with this is that it includes the address at the end of the document.
2. Enter it manually. I enter the address in standard mode then center it but there's still too much spacing between the author and the address (e.g., when I put .1 cm of vertical space, I get over an inch of space in the PDF).

How can I enter my address so that it appears as in the picture above AND does not part of Author? If I need to directly change the source code (i.e., editing the preamble, settings or entering an ERT), please include some detail on how I can go about that.

**MWE**

```
 \documentclass[oneside,english]{amsart}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{amsthm}

 \makeatletter
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
 \numberwithin{equation}{section}
 \numberwithin{figure}{section}

 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
 \title[Short version]{Long version}
 \usepackage{mathtools}

 \makeatother

 \usepackage{babel}
 \begin{document}

 \title{{\small{Title}}}


 \author{Author\\
 }


 \address{Address }\maketitle

 \end{document}
```

Comment: Please consider adding a minimal example to all of your questions. See for example wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample. As for your question, I believe that behavior is determined by the class/style so you are asking for a way to override the default behavior.

Comment: Good point, I've edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have the ultimate control over where this content is displayed and whether/not it ends up elsewhere in the document, I would patch `\@maketitle` in the Document > Settings... > LaTeX Preamble using [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox):

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\patchcmd{\@maketitle}% <cmd>
  {\ifx\@empty\@dedicatory}% <search>
  {\smallskip
    \begin{center}
    \footnotesize% Size of the address content
    \begin{tabular}{c}
      Department of Who Cares \\
      University of Nowhere \\
      Randomville, RND
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
  \ifx\@empty\@dedicatory}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
```

The above patch inserts the address just after setting the authors - `\@setauthors` - and just before the dedicatory - `\@dedicatory`. Note that some other packages may redefine `\@maketitle`. This patch works under the default definition of `\@maketitle`, which forms part of [`amsart`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsart).

[image]

[image]

Comment: When I copy and paste your message, I receive "LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}." If I insert \begin{document} after \usepackage{etoolbox} I am able to obtain the PDF, but the address doesn't appear.

Comment: @TheSubstitute: You may have to wrap the entire `\patchcmd` content within a `\makeatletter` ... `\makeatother` construction. See [What do `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` do?](http://goo.gl/HYwLd) However, I've seen LyX automatically wrap the entire LaTeX Preamble within those. If this still doesn't fix the problem, could you post your `.tex` from LyX in [Pastebin](http://pastebin.org).

Comment: I included those codes at the end but still not showing up. What is `.tex`? Is that different from a MWE?

Comment: @TheSubstitute: The "Complete source" provided by LyX. You can also provide the `.lyx` source. Something that'll allow me to replicate your current problem. Otherwise it's difficult to fix.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/KSZmcs39

Comment: @TheSubstitute: I can't replicate your problem. The source you provided doesn't include my suggested patch. And, even though I include it [I can still see the address properly displayed](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WbQ9x.png).

Comment: Sorry about that. Here's another http://pastebin.com/MxzE8Kcm. In this one I include your patch (starting at line 45), but I include `\begindocument` since I'm not able to create a PDF otherwise. I just checked and the address does not appear in my PDF.

Comment: @TheSubstitute: Okay, I see now. Remove `\usepackage{babel}` from the LaTeX Preamble, as it is already included elsewhere in your document settings. Then, use `\makeatletter \patchcmd{..}{..}{..}{}{} \makeatother`, since it seems like it didn't get included as expected.

Comment: @TheSubstitute: Does that work?